# How i Validate the correct format file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am uploading Excel file and i want when i click on upload button if its Excel file its show the msg "File Uploaded Sucessfully" otherwise its incorrect file i.e img. doc etc its show the msg "you must be select the Excel Format file" kindly help how i do this on AJAX.

This is my Controller its uploading sucessfully.

```html
//Post
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Email_Load")]
        public ActionResult Email_Load_confirmed(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            File_Model tz = new File_Model();
            
            try
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Contacts.xls"));
                    _Stores Stores_ = new _Stores();
                    Basic_Helper _Basic_Helper = new Basic_Helper();
                    var Store = Stores_.Get_Store_Info_Prd(_Basic_Helper.Format_URL(Request.Url.Host.ToString()));
                    if (Store != null)
                    {
                        _Basic_Helper = null;
                        _Site_Info Site_Info = new _Site_Info();
                        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Contacts.xls") + ";";
                        connectionString += "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                        // always read from the sheet1.
                        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$];");
                        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        myConnection.Open();
                        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                        OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (!myReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Equals(""))
                            {
                                Site_Info.Insert_Cust_Det_Newsletter(Store.ID, myReader.GetValue(0).ToString(), myReader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        myReader.Close();
                        myCommand.Cancel();
                        myConnection.Close();
                        myConnection = null;
                        Site_Info = null;
                    }
                    Store = null;
                    Stores_ = null;
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Contacts.xls"));

                
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
                s = "";
               // Response.Write(ex.ToString());
         
                
            }

            return View();
        }
```

its Razor View

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email_Load", "Marketing", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{   

  <table class="a_m_s">  
      <tr>
  <td>File:   </td>
     <td>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" data-show-preview="false" style="border: 4px solid rgb(224, 0, 0);
padding: 1px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background: rgb(85, 85, 85) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; clear:both; margin-top:10px;"></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> <br />
     <input type="submit" id="load" value="Upload File" style=" background-color: #e00000; clear: both; color: #fff; border: 3px solid #e00000; margin-left: 10px;"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

 }
```

Then How i do on AJax???

Thanks Regards,

Tahir

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of uploading a file via Ajax  which includes a check for Excel files. This will not work in IE9 or below. If you need to upload with older browsers I would suggest a plugin like:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

**Client/Browser:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var fileUpload = function() {
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    // do stuff...
                } else {
                    alert("Upload Failed. Your request was not completed successfully; reason: " + this.statusText);
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                alert("A network related error occurred when trying to process this request. Please check your connection and try again.");
            };

            xhr.open("POST", "/Home/UploadExcel", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            xhr.send(file);
        };

        $("#load").on("click", function () {
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
            var fileName = file.name;
            var fileExtension = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));

            if (fileExtension === "xls" || fileExtension === "xlsx") {
                fileUpload();
            } else {
                alert("Must be Excel file");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadExcel()
{
    var error = true;
    var errorMessage = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (Request.InputStream != null)
        {
            //do stuff...
            error = false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "File was null";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        errorMessage = "Problem in uploading excel file; reason: " + x.Message;
    }

    var dto = new
    {
        error,
        errorMessage
    };

    return Json(dto);
}
```